# Show that $V = \{\mathrm{id}, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$ is a normal subgroup of $\operatorname{Sym}(4)$...

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Show that $V = \{\mathrm{id}, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$ is a normal subgroup of $\operatorname{Sym}(4)$, and that $G/V$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Sym}(3)$. (The group $V$ is the Klein $4$-group.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitions are your friend! Review: "Normal subgroup", "quotient group", "isomorphic"...

First, confirm that $V$ is indeed a subgroup of $S_4$, which is easy enough to do.

Then: Can you show that $gVg^{-1} = V$ for all $g \in G = S_4$? That's one way to show that $V$ is *normal* in $S_4$.

Once you've shown that $V$ is a normal subgroup of $S_4$, then determine $[S_4 : V] = |S_4|/V|$, and show that the *quotient group* $S_4/V$ must be be *isomorphic* to $S_3$.

Comment: You also need to prove that it is a subgroup!

Comment: How would I prove that it is a subgroup? I know that sym(4) has 24 permutations, of which 4 belong to the Klein four-group so it is a subgroup but I don't think that's a very good proof and I wouldn't want to list all 24 permutations.

Comment: You can show that it is a subgroup of Sym(4) by showing it obviously contains the identity of Sym(4), every non-identity element is its own inverse (so closed under inversion), and that permuting any two elements in V gives an element in V, and hence is closed. There you go, V is therefore a subgroup of Sym(4).

Comment: For showing it's a normal subgroup, I am instructed to use Hg=gH for all g in G. This requires the use of cosets I believe but I don't know what each g will be. How do I find this right g and this left g? Are they permutations? Thanks for all your help, I'm sorry I must seem so awful at algebra!

Comment: Yes, they are permutations: Sym(4) are permutations of four numbers $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$. For showing its a *normal* subgroup, pick an arbitrary $g$ in Sym(4): and use h in V: you can show that all g in Sym(4) belong to one of 6 cosets of V: and the left cosets of V = right cosets of V.

Comment: So would (12)(34)g = g(12)(34) be an example? How would I show that they are equal? Yeah, I saw that there were 6 cosets for sym(4) on wikipedia, are 3 left and 3 right?

Comment: Yes, that would make an example. But because hg = gh for all h in V and g in Sym(4), the six cosets of V in Sym(4) are left and right cosets: that's why V is normal in Sym(4).

Comment: Would I just do that for each of the 4 elements in V? That somehow gives 6 different cosets and not 4?

Comment: Yes there are 6 cosets of of V in Sym(4), each coset has 4 elements, which is the number of elements in V.

Comment: I can't see how I'll get 6 cosets if g is only being multiplied by the 4 elements of V? To me I see that as getting 4? And how would I actually compute one... The (12)(34)g=g(12)(34). Last questions I promise! Ha. Thanks though, you've been so helpful!

Comment: Because there are 24 elements in Sym(4), and 4 elements in the subgroup V. Since every coset will have 4 elements (the number of elements in V), there will be 24/4 = 6 cosets. That is, the index of V in Sym(G) [G : V] is 6.

Answer (score 3):

Let's to examine the concrete approach which @amWhy pointed by [GAP 4.7.2](http://www.gap-system.org/Releases/index.html) as follows:

```
gap> S4:=SymmetricGroup(IsPermGroup,4);;
     V:= Group((),(1,2)*(3,4),(1,3)*(2,4),(1,4)*(2,3));;
     e:=Elements(S4);;
     f:=Elements(V);;
gap> for i in [1..Size(g)] do 
       for j in [1..4] do 
     Print(e[i]^(-1)*f[j]*e[i] in f, "\n");
       od;
     od;

 true
```